# jquery validation does not work with SelectBoxIt component

Tags: jquery, validation

I  have installed SelectBoxIt in order to change my select box look&feel, but I have found the problem is that jquery validation does not work, for example if this field is required.

It is no necessary me to post the code because it is easy to reproduce (I tried but stackoverflow page hung). Just include jquery.validate.min.js and jquery.selectBoxIt.min.js, then create a dropdownlist with some elements, having the first one, an empty value.

The rules to define are:

```
                'Cliente[cnaid]': {
                    required: true,
                    min: 1
                },
```

where Cliente[cnaid] is the name of the select box.

Any hint will be greatly appreciated,

Thanks
Jaime

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jQuery Validate works by default only on visible form elements.  SelectBoxIt hides the default select and displays one built out of non-form elements.  What you need to do is add the option to your `validate` call to allow it to validate hidden elements:

```
$('form').validate({
  ignore:'', //i.e. do not ignore hidden elements
  //rules, etc
});
```

Comment: @jstuardo - Cool, you need to check out the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) on the topic of voting and accepting answers (and go back and do the same on all your previous questions!)

Comment: its working on localhost. but not working on hosting server.